# How to create query for elasticsearch by spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I hope to execute a query and the condition is that one field not existing. I only know that we are able to use exists() to retrieve the data when the field existing. But I cannot find any api for no field existing case.

[Query Example]

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.and(new Criteria("field_a").exists());
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);
elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(criteriaQuery, OrderLine.class);
```

Could you please advise how I should use the spring-data-elasticsearch api

Answer (score 0):

Just add not() to the criteria:

```java
criteria.and(new Criteria("field_a").exists().not());
```